# Ajax Request to Web Method Returning document object instead of text or JSON

Tags: c#, ajax, json, jquery, webmethod

I have an ajax call to a web service which I'd like to return some JSON back to the view. Right now, though, if I alert the result of the call, I get "object Document". I tried changing the content type around but no dice. Here is the ajax call in its current state:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "services/offerService.asmx/getUploadedDocs",
    contentType: 'text/html',
    data: {offerID : offerId},
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(index) {
        alert(result.toString());
        $(element).closest('ul.uploadedDocs').append('<li id="uploadedDoc-'+(index+"") + '" class = "uploadedDocument"><span id="uploadedDocTitle">Title: '+ result["title"] + '</span><span id="uploadedDocUploadedBy>Uploaded By: ' + result["uploadedBy"] + '</span></li>');
        });                     
    }
});
```

And here's the web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public object getUploadedDocs(string offerID)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[uploaded_documents] WHERE primary_offer_id = @offerId";
    IList<UploadedDocument> uploadedDocs = new List<UploadedDocument>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["production"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@offerId", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@offerId"].Value = offerID;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        adapter.Dispose();
        uploadedDocs = dt.ToList<UploadedDocument>();
    }

    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    json.Append("{");
    int count = 1;
    foreach (UploadedDocument doc in uploadedDocs)
    {
        json.Append("{doc"+count.ToString()+":"+"{\"title\": " + doc.docTitle + ", \"uploadedBy\": " + doc.uploadedBy + ", \"uploadDate\": " + doc.uploadDate.ToLongDateString() + "},");
    }
    if(json.ToString().Contains(","))
        json = json.Remove(json.ToString().LastIndexOf(','), 1);
    json.Append("}");
    return json.ToString();
}
```

I could send it back as a `object()`, probably, but I'd much rather leave it as a string and have it be parsed as JSON. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change the contentType in your ajax call to 'json'.

Then try calling

```
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

and see what that gives you.  Assuming you are constructing the json object properly, it should be working.  Also download [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/downloads) and see what is being returned.

Edit:

I'm not sure what your uploadedDocs object looks like but try doing

```
return Json(uploadedDocs);
```

in your method.

JK you're using WebForms (?) so to parse it to a Json object see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482758/how-to-convert-an-object-list-into-json-in-asp-net)

Comment: JSON or application/json? I had the latter in there previously and was getting the same result.

Comment: contentType is the type you are sending to the server, so whatever offerID is.  You want to set the dataType to 'json', which is the type you are receiving from the server.

Comment: Honestly I usually don't set either.  JS will use context to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, me neither. That's why I'm curious on this. The framework is pretty good about coercing your data into whatever data type is most convenient..

Comment: I set it up to return an object of the form new{data = myData}, and now it's sending back text/plain in the response.. So maybe this is a framework issue more than it is a coding issue, I dunno..

Comment: What assembly is `Json` a part of?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WebForms but I linked to a SO question about Json serialization for you.  I'm losing track of the core problem, though.  Is the call to alert in your ajax function displaying your data now?

Comment: Nope. It's coming back as text/plain now. It's actually not a web forms app, it's just a vanilla asp.net site. If it were up to me, I'd be using MVC and this would be easy :P